# Getting "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character" when saving to a text file in Windows

Tags: python, file-io, windows-7, ascii

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7. My program generates some numbers (range 0-255) and then converts them into ascii characters (chr) and creates a string. Now I want to save contents of this string in a text file. It gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8e' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please note that the length of the string is variable and any and all codes (0-255) can occur.

Sample code:

```
file = open('somefiliename.txt', 'w')
file.write(result) #result being the string variable containing ascii chars.
file.close()
```

I can print the result string and there is no error using print(result). But it is not saving to a file.

result = ''
for y in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        result += chr(matrix[x, y])
print(result)

The code is pretty long, i have added above the pertinent. matrix is a numpy 2-dimensional (4x4) matrix which stores the numbers.

Comment: @AnandSKumar code is below: result = ''
for y in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        result += chr(matrix[x, y])

print(result)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Windows 7, using a simple code like -

```
>>> s = ''
>>> for i in range(256):
...     s += chr(i)
...
>>>
>>> f = open('a.txt','w')
>>> f.write(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 129-160: character maps to <undefined>
```

And the characters in position 129 start at `\x81` , etc.

The issue occurs because you are openning your file with a default encoding, if you really want to write those characters into your file, you should open it with `utf8` encoding , also specify the newline argument to `''` (Why? Explained below). Example -

```
>>> f = open('a.txt','w',encoding="utf8",newline='')
>>> f.write(s)
257
>>> f.close()
```

For those using Python 2.x , they can use `codecs.open()` to open the file with a specific encoding.

---

Also for Python 3.x , you would have issues when reading back this file, as when reading back you would see the ASCII value 13 - (Carriage return - `'\r'`) has been converted to `'\n'`) . This is because in Python 3.x , if we do not specify the newline argument for `open()` function (which means it is None), it will use universal newline (which will convert all - `\r\n` , `\r` , `\n` to `\n`) . From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open) -

> newline controls how universal newlines works (it only applies to text
>   mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'. It works as
>   follows:
>
> 1. On input, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled.
>      Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are
>      translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. If it is '',
>      universal newline mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to
>      the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values,
>      input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line
>      ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> 2. On output, if newline is None, any '\n' characters written are translated to the system default line separator, os.linesep. If newline is '', no translation takes place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any '\n' characters written are translated to the given string.

In your case, you should specify `newline=''` argument while both writing as well as reading the file.

Example of reading -

```
>>> f= open('b.txt','r',newline='',encoding='utf8')
>>> x = f.read()
>>> print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, it has helped. i have added the code above. the use of encoding="utf8" has worked and now the string is getting saved. But I have noticed that wherever the ascii code 13 was used, in the file it is converted to ascii code 10. Please help with this. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulQadir Seems like an issue with python, in the notepad++ , it correctly shows only `CR` for line with ascii 13, and `CRLF` for line with ascii 10.